# Masonry overlaps my footer

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm using Masonry to create a grid of posts, but as you can see in my example below, the masonry div/boxes overlaps my footer. Any ideas to make the footer start after the masonry div?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CkhUQ/

CSS for footer and container that wraps masonry:

```
footer {
width:100%;
background:#CCC;
height:400px;
}
#container {
max-width:1260px;
width:calc(100% - 40px);
min-height:1500px;
margin:auto;
top:187px;
position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/CkhUQ/8/

The correct solution and CAUSE for this is because you set

```
#container {
    max-width:1260px;
    width:calc(100% - 40px);
    min-height:1500px;
    margin:auto;
    top:187px;
    position:relative;
}
```

the top:187px; part is the cause of this
as its potion didn't change when you pushed the content down.
trying using padding-top to replace and then the containing div
box will size accordingly and gets pushed down so no overlap will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding-bottom: 300px;` to your #container element.  You can play around with the number, but it should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, that made me realise something. I think it's doing this because of the `top:187px` so if I add `margin-bottom:187px` it seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

How about with a header div and display block on the container div followed by a clear both div:
http://jsfiddle.net/shJNj/1/

```
#container {
    max-width:1260px;
    width:calc(100% - 40px);
    min-height:1500px;
    margin:auto;
    display: block;
}

<div id="header" style="height: 187px;"></div>
<div id="container">

<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<footer></footer>
```